Purpose of wires of ESC
I have a brushless sensored DC ESC. The Manufucturer doesn't have instructions. I probably know the purpose of every wire. The three thick wires are for the motor phases, the three wires together (white, red,black) are for the PWM. Right? But I don't understand, why there is an input for a 6-pin-cable. Could someone pls tell me, because the only option is that it is for the hall effect sensors of the motor, but then it would be 3 not 6?




Without wires it would be wireless.

You mean it wouldn't be sensored without the 6-pin-cable? or what

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Could someone pls tell me, because the only option is that it is for the hall effect sensors of the motor, but then it would be 3 not 6?

Without manufacturer instructions it is not obvious how the hall effect sensors are expected to be connected. On a search for possible connection topologies found:

Designing the 3-Phase Brushless DC Motor shows a 3 phase BLDC motor with three two pin hall sensors which then requires 6 pins:


How to Connect Brushless DC Motors to an Electronic Controller shows a different possible topology which uses 5 pins, 3 hall effect outputs, voltage supply and ground:




.....................

EY. But did I understand it right, that my motor isn'T compatible with the ESC then?
